# No webpack.config.js file after using nativescript "tns create my-tab-ng --template tns-template-tab-navigation-ng" template

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

Anytime I try to run command `tns run android` with a device connected to my computer, an error occurs that `webpack.config.js` file was not found. I created the project using `tns create my-tab-ng --template tns-template-tab-navigation-ng`. Isn't the template supposed to create the `webpack.config.js` file? Please what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had excactly the same problem and by luck I could solve it. I hope it also works for you.
I don't even remember why I set this config, I think I read somewhere that it is recommended but it definitely brought me a lot of pain and time waste:

Check you settings with this:
***npm config get ignore-scripts***

if it returns true, set it to false with this:
***npm config set ignore-scripts false***

Answer (score 0):

Try to migrate

```
ng migrate --force
```

it will add webpack.config.js for you